# NASM pads section to 512 bytes

Tags: alignment, nasm, sections

NASM compiler stubbornly pads my data section with 0s making it 512 bytes in size. I can't figure out what happens. As per the documentation the default section alignments are much smaller. Here's en excerpt from the .map file

```
Vstart            Start             Stop              Length    Class     Name
               0                 0               200  00000200  progbits  .text
               0               200               250  00000050  progbits  data
               0               400               600  00000200  progbits  code
```

Here are lines from my .asm which I believe may be of concern

```
...  ; some code
ALIGN 512

[SECTION data VSTART=0]
BITS 32
...  ; some data
ALIGN 16

[SECTION code VSTART=0]
...  ; some code
ALIGN 512
```

And here's the command line I use to compile it
 `c:\nasm\nasm.exe -f bin secondary.asm -o secondary.bin`

With this setup I expect the code section to start at 250 but it starts at 400. Could someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Use a `sectalign off` directive first thing in the source code. Because you used `align 512` in section "code" its alignment was increased to that number. It doesn't matter to NASM that it is `vstart=0`

Comment: @ecm Thank you very much! It worked and by the same occasion I've learned that ALIGN N macro implicitely calls SECTALIGN N if SECTALIGN OFF is not called excplicitely.